# Crashlytics does not show stacktrace for NDK reports

Tags: android, android-ndk, crashlytics, linphone

I compiled the Linphone project. It works most of the time, but sometimes it crashes in the native layer. I followed the instructions in [Crashlytics documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ndk-reports) to enable NDK crash reports. It works, but it does not show the stacktrace of the problem. It shows something like this:
[Information shown in Crashlytics for native exceptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1yzu.jpg)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Fabric/Firebaser here -

Based on that screenshot, your setup to capture NDK crashes with Crashlytics should be mostly correct, but missing the symbols required to symbolicate your native crash stacktraces. Crashlytics requires two versions of your native libraries - one with the symbols stripped out, and one with the symbol information preserved (unstripped). Once it locates the pairs of libraries that it needs (one pair per native library, per architecture you support), it will generate symbol files. A few things can get in the way of Crashlytics getting that information:

- Crashlytics looks for a particular project structure to find your libraries by default: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/ndk.html#specifying-the-path-to-debug-and-release-binaries. If it fails to find this structure, it can fail to generate symbol files. You can manually control the paths to the stripped and unstripped libraries using the `androidNdkOut` and `androidNdkLibsOut` fields in your build.gradle.
- Check that the libraries that you're using provide the symbols necessary to symbolicate crashes from the libraries in the first place. You can run `file <path-to-binary>` to see if the libraries are stripped or not stripped.
- At times, there are build processes that can further strip out symbols or further optimize the libraries you're including in your app, causing symbolication to fail.

Your crashlytics.log file will have a lot more information about Crashlytics trying to parse your project and generate symbol files. You can check that here:

**On Linux/Windows:** ~/.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log

**On Mac:** ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log

If you're still running into issues getting symbolicated stacktraces, reach out to support@fabric.io or submit a case to https://firebase.google.com/support.